# Using arrays to compare char

Tags: c

I'm coding this pattern game, but I am having difficulties in storing the previous input of the users "uno" and "dos" to a array so it can be compared, if same it will ask for another input which has not been picked. Example of This

```
Round 1:
Player 1 Inputs : -> A
Player 2 Inputs : -> B
Valid

Round 2:
 Player 1 Inputs : -> L
 Player 2 Inputs  : -> V
Valid
Round 3:
Player 1 Inputs : -> A (Invalid Already been used)
enter char again
```

That above is an example i am trying to achieve. I will post the code below. I would appreciate the help very much.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SWITCH(_g0,_g1) \
(_g0 << 8) | (_g1 << 0)
#define CASE(_g0,_g1) \
case SWITCH(_g0,_g1)

intgetval(const char *prompt)
{
char *cp;
char buf[100];
int val;
 while (1) {
printf("%s: ",prompt);
    fflush(stdout);
cp = fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin);
 // handle end of file
    if (cp == NULL) {
        val = -1;
        break;

    // get the first char on the line
    val = buf[0];
    if (val != '\n')
        break;
 }
return val;
}




int main ()
{


int i = 0;
int roundCount = 1;
int pos = 0;
int over = 0;
int f = 1;
char G[9];
char uno,dos;
 printf("Game Start!\n");

do {
    printf("Round %d!\n", roundCount++);
    printf("Input selection upon prompt.\n");

    printf("Player 1: ");
    scanf(" %c", &uno );
    printf("Player 2: ");
    scanf(" %c", &dos);

 

    if()
    
    //printf("DEBUG: %2.2X %2.2X\n",G[0],G[1]);

    switch (SWITCH(uno,dos)) {
CASE('L','V'):
    CASE('V','S'):
    CASE('S','P'):
    CASE('P','R'):
    CASE('R','L'):
    CASE('R','S'):
    CASE('P','V'):
    CASE('S','L'):
    CASE('V','R'):
    CASE('L','P'):
        f++;
        pos--;
        printf("Uno Wins!   Pos[%d]\n\n", pos);
        break;
 CASE('R','P'):
    CASE('L','R'):
    CASE('R','V'):
    CASE('P','S'):
    CASE('P','L'):
    CASE('S','R'):
    CASE('S','V'):
    CASE('L','S'):
    CASE('V','P'):
    CASE('V','L'):
        f++;
        pos++;
        printf("Dos Wins    Pos[%d]!\n\n", pos);
        break;
 CASE('R','R'):
    CASE('P','P'):
    CASE('S','S'):
    CASE('L','L'):
    CASE('V','V'):
        f++;
        pos = pos;
        break;
    }
if (pos == -3 || pos == 3) {
        printf("Game over\n");
        break;
    }
if (f == 5 && pos != -3 && pos != 3) {
        switch (SWITCH(uno,dos)) {
        CASE('L','V'):
        CASE('V','S'):
        CASE('S','P'):
        CASE('P','R'):
        CASE('R','L'):
        CASE('R','S'):
        CASE('P','V'):
        CASE('S','L'):
        CASE('V','R'):
        CASE('L','P'):
        printf("Uno:Wins!\n");
            break;
 CASE('R','P'):
        CASE('L','R'):
        CASE('R','V'):
        CASE('P','S'):
        CASE('P','L'):
        CASE('S','R'):
        CASE('S','V'):
        CASE('L','S'):
        CASE('V','P'):
        CASE('V','L'):
            printf("Dos Win!\n");
            break;
        }
 }
} while (f < 5);
return 0;
}
```

im trying to implement a for loop for this but it wouldn't work , i am not getting the result that i want, adding this code. I would appreciate it if you would rewrite the code with this loop or if there is any other way please tell me how.

```
for ( i = 0; i < sizeof(useduno); i++)
{
if (uno == useduno[i]) // where useduno is the array, where uno is to be stored, so it cannot be used again 
    {
printf("You already used the letter. Use another letter: ");
      scanf(" %c", &uno);
}
}
```

Comment: One comment: Do yourself a favour and ditch the macros. Just create functions. The chances are they'll be inlined anyway so don't have a cost when the program is run.

Comment: @PaulRooney Those macros can't be replaced with functions without a major rewrite of the code that uses them.

Comment: It's a really quite clever way of switching on two values.

Comment: Johnny Abella, `intgetval()` is never used. Why is it part of the post?

Comment: `useduno[]` is not defined.  `if()` not valid.  Post a [mcve].

Comment: @Shawn a major rewrite is exactly what this code needs.